# ssl certificate or nginx proxy server not working

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have created a domain(domain.com) and subdomain (abc.domain.com), and also generated SSL certificates for both by using letsencrypt. Both the Django projects are hosted on AWS EC2 and created proxy server for them which is as follow:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://1.2.3.4:444;
        proxy_ssl_server_name       on;
        proxy_ssl_verify            on;
        proxy_ssl_certificate      /home/domain/fullchain.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key  /home/domain/privkey.pem;
    }
}


server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name abc.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://1.2.3.4:445;
        proxy_ssl_server_name       on;
        proxy_ssl_verify            on;
        proxy_ssl_certificate      /home/subdomain/fullchain.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key  /home/subdomain/privkey.pem;
    }
}
```

I strats the proxy server and both the projects, starting  not giving any problem the problem is that when i enter `https://example.com` on the browser it is not showing the page, but when i pull domain with port no. `https://example.com:444`, it starts showing the page. I do not know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `https://example.com` work you need to correctly configure Nginx with SSL configuration which include using `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives as it does not seem that you are using them.

Using `proxy_ssl_certificate` is for using HTTPS connection between Nginx and the Proxied Server which in your case the django application.

Using `ssl_certificate` is for using HTTPS connection between the user's browser and Nginx which you need to make `https://example.com` works as expected

For more details check [configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Comment: `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` need to removed from location @mostafa

Comment: I am not sure about this as the documentation mentioned that these directive for the communication between Nginx and what goes behind it and does not say anything about using it with `ssl_certificate` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_certificate unlike `ssl_certificate` will be between the browser and nginx itself

Comment: Do you have a conflict while using both `ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate` ?

Comment: please post the error you have. Generally speaking to make `https://example.com` work you need to use `ssl_certificate` and so on.